# Intended ObservableCollection +NotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: inotifypropertychanged

Greetings, 
I have some List of objects of Type CMessage. CMessage can look as follows:

```
public ROWGUID {get;set;}
public ObservableCollection<CAnswer> Answers 
{
get {return  _Answer;}
set 
{_Answer=value
RaisePropertyChanged("Answer");
}

}
```

each property has RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged method which Is implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged interface. 
The point is:

1. I select some Message From the list of ObservableCollection Messages;
2. I add some Answers to my selected message

Why There is no RaisePropertyChanged executed for that message? It should!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
// get some Message from OC<Message> collection Message
var message = Messages.First(); 
message.Answers.Add(new CAnswer { Text = "HURRDURR" }); // add an answer
```

but your CMessage will only call RaisePropertyChanged when you do this

```
var message = Messages.First();
var answers = new ObservableCollection<CAnswer>();
answers.Add(new CAnswer { Text = "LOL" });
message.Answers = answers; // triggers here
```

The first raises the CollectionChanged event of the Answers collection.  The second changes the Answers collection which will cause your `set` method to fire, which raises the PropertyChanged event of your CMessage class.

BTW, you're doing this wrong.  You shouldn't let people set your collection property.  It isn't a best practice, allows the property to be set to null (which is bad), etc.  You should only have read-only property collections.  If users are interested in the property changing they should subscribe to the CollectionChanged event of your property.